# Hiding Border/Shadow After Header in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a header and then a custom header in my react native app - so one sits on top of the other - as desired, so I can extend the height and add some additional content.

The only issue I'm running into is the thin white border between them. I have tried to hide that with `headerShadowVisible: false` within `screenOptions` of the `Tab.Navigator` but it's not working. What do I need to add to remove the border or shadow below the first header?

```
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: true,
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
    },
    headerShadowVisible: false, // This has no effect
    tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: Colors.primary },
    headerTintColor: Colors.light,
    title: `${props.customer?.firstName} ${props.customer?.lastName}`,
    tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors.light,
    tabBarInactiveTintColor: Colors.lightInactive,
    tabBarActiveBackgroundColor: Colors.primary,
    tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor: Colors.primary,
    headerLeft: () => (
      <Feather
        name='chevron-left'
        size={24}
        onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack()}
        color={styles.colors.textInverse}
        style={styles.layout.padding.horizontal}
      />
    ),
  }}
  initialRouteName={'Sessions'}
>

return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Header {...headerOptions} />
  </View>
  // Other code
);
```

Second custom header options:

```
const headerOptions = {
  headerShadowVisible: false, // Has no apparent effect
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
    shadowColor: 'transparent', // this covers iOS
    elevation: 0, // this covers Android
    headerShadowVisible: false,
  },
  headerLeft: () => (
    <View style={{ ...styles.layout.headerLeft, paddingLeft: 10 }}>
      <Text
        style={{
          color: styles.colors.textInverse,
          fontSize: 15,
        }}
      >
        {this.props.session.type.value}
      </Text>
    </View>
  ),
  headerRight: () => (
    <View style={{ paddingRight: 10 }}>
      <Text
        style={{
          color: styles.colors.textInverse,
          fontSize: 15,
        }}
      >
        {moment(this.props.visit.date).format('MMM Do YYYY')}
      </Text>
    </View>
  ),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[first is Custom header and second is from RN check img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lKgT.png)
fist create a custom header under that u can use you navigation-top-tab bar from react native
render header in topTabNavigation component!
so that will work according to me!
please check my code!

```js
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs";  
// use this library



const TopTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();



function TopTabScreen() {
    const { height } = Dimensions.get("window");
    const total_tdo = useSelector(
      (state) => state.mainReducer.TotalTdoCount || 0
    );
    // console.log("total_tdo", total_tdo);
    const total_taluka = useSelector(
      (state) => state.mainReducer.TotalTalukaCount || 0
    );
    const total_town = useSelector(
      (state) => state.mainReducer.TotalTownCount || 0
    );
    const total_project = useSelector(
      (state) => state.mainReducer.TotalProjectCount || 0
    );
    // console.log("Tproject in store:", total_project);
    return (
      <TopTab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarLabelStyle: {
            fontSize: height < 684 ? normalizeText(10.5) : normalizeText(11.5),
            fontWeight: "bold",
            color: "white",
            elevation: 10,
          },
          tabBarStyle: {
            backgroundColor: GlobalStyles.colors.mainC,
          },
          tabBarIndicatorStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "white",
            height: scale(5),
            borderTopLeftRadius: scale(4),
            borderTopRightRadius: scale(4),
            elevation: 10,
          },
        }}
      >
        <TopTab.Screen
          name={"Tab-Tdo"}
          component={TdoScreen}
          options={{
            title: `TDO ( ${total_tdo} )`,
          }}
        />
        <TopTab.Screen
          name={"Tab-Taluka"}
          component={TalukaScreen}
          options={{
            title: `Taluka( ${total_taluka} )`,
          }}
        />
        <TopTab.Screen
          name={"Tab-Town"}
          component={TownScreen}
          options={{
            title: `Town( ${total_town} )`,
          }}
        />
        <TopTab.Screen
          name={"Tab-Projects"}
          component={ProjectScreen}
          options={{
            title: `Project( ${total_project} )`,
            // tabBarLabelStyle: {
            //   fontSize: height < 684 ? scale(10) : scale(12),
            //   fontWeight: "bold",
            //   color: "white",
            // },
          }}
        />
      </TopTab.Navigator>
    );
  }
    
    
    
    //Main Return of Component
      return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="TopBarTab"
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: true,
          **header: () => <MainHeader />,//custom header**
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="Header" component={MainHeader} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Stack-Tdo" component={TdoScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Stack-Taluka" component={TalukaScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Stack-Town" component={TownScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Stack-Projects" component={ProjectScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="TopBarTab" component={TopTabScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

Comment: I should not have to create a customHeader just to remove the border shadow. This is not really an answer to the question as poised. I know your new around here, but to post an answer it's important that you answer the question as it's actually asked.